# Copyright, Outright Copying and Client Requirements

Tags: copyright, legal

I've been asked to recreate some vector artwork based on an image supplied by my client "from the internet". I told them I cannot copy it exactly but can create something of a similar nature.  "Oh if we just change it 10% it's fine", was the response. Mmmhmm.

I've investigated further and found the image was created by an artist craftsman who does some amazing work, so obviously I'm not prepared to recreate it but what are my options here?  She's hell bent on the supplied design. Do I suggest something completely different?  Do I leave it completely alone?

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would give the client the name of the artist whose work she is interested in and recommend to her she hires that artist to do the work she wants. She didn’t find public domain artwork to copy — she found an artist.

Bill her for the time you spent finding the artist for her. Then move on to the next job.

Comment: We already have a Q&A similar to this.  I would encourage you to leave an answer there in case this Q&A gets deleted for being a duplicate.

Comment: Shall do, cheers.  I ended up telling her the name of the artist and aside from it breaching copyright law if we used it, I couldn't do it ethically. Not heard back yet.